# VS2013 is >7GB, can I slim this down?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

My development machine has a 128G SSD. I recently upgraded to VS2013 Ultimate, and found that it ate 7.3G of it. In comparison, my VS2010 takes up just over 500M.

I cannot imagine why this is so much larger, and suspect I have a bunch of stuff on here I don't need. Does anyone have any way to characterize where that space is going, and what I might be able to do to get some of it back?

Comment: The phone SDK is huge due to the VMs. If you don't need that you can save a bunch.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I looked in the installer and turned off a few options, but it only removed maybe 300 MB. Is it safe to simply remove the VM's I won't be using (which is all of them)?

Answer (score -2):

No, you cannot.

Per the [Microsoft website](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-ultimate-with-msdn-vs#Fragment_SystemRequirements), VS 2013 requires 20GB.

**Hardware requirements**

- 1.6 GHz or faster processor
- 1 GB of RAM (1.5 GB if running on a virtual machine)
- 20 GB of available hard disk space
- 5400 RPM hard disk drive
- DirectX 9-capable video card that runs at 1024 x 768 or higher
  display resolution

I am surprised that you're around 7GB

---

Maybe you should look at [VS2013 Online Advanced](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-online-advanced-vs), if you're really interested in HD space:

**Hardware requirements**

- 1.6 GHz or faster processor
- 1 GB of RAM (1.5 GB if running on a virtual machine)
- 5 GB of available hard disk space
- 5400 RPM hard drive
- DirectX 9-capable video card running at 1024 x 768 or higher display
  resolution

<sub>I Google so that you don't have to™</sub>

Comment: Can't use Online at the cottage. All non-Online versions claim 20 GB but none of them actually use that, so the specs are simply wrong.

VS2010 with many, many installed add-ons is 500MB. I find it extremely difficult to believe that even MS could manage to increase that TWELVE TIMES. Oh well, back to 2010 I guess.

Comment: Did you -1 me because you didn't like the answer or because the answer was wrong?

Comment: Because it doesn't answer the question. Fine for a comment, but not an answer.

Comment: updated it to directly answer the question.  Now, you could only downvote if you don't like my answer - which is correct.

Comment: I'm sorry I've offended you, but the answer remains a non-answer... (1) the system clearly does *not* require 20 GB no matter what MS says, (2) it *is* possible to slim it down, as the note above demonstrates, and (3) you have not addressed the issue of what is using up this space or how to find out, which was the original question.

Comment: Nah, you didn't offend me.  However... look at the other answers.  Sometimes we want an answer that is appealing to us - even if it's not practical.  **People in hell want ice water... I can't help them either.**  Just FYI, your question has changed from "can you" to "how can I".  I believe this is what you really want to ask.  That being the case, my answer is (as you suggest) moot.